# AWS ECS Fargate CannotPullContainerError: ref pull has been retried failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: unexpected status code

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

From ECS console I started to see this issue

[image]

I think I understand pretty well the cause of this. ECS pulls these images as an anonymous user, since I haven't provided any credentials, and since the task was set to run every 5 minutes it was hitting the anonymous quota. No big deal, I set the task to run every 10 minutes and for now the problem is solved.

What drives me nuts is:

- From CloudWatch console you can see that the task was executed. If I graph the number of executions I will see a chart with data points every 5 minutes. This is wrong to me, because in order to execute the task ECS first needs to pull something, and it can't, therefore there is no execution.
- I can't find the error `(CannotPullContainerError: ref pull has been retried 1 time(s): failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: unexpected status code https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/amazon/aws-for-fluent-bit/manifests/sha256:f134723f733ba4f3489c742dd8cbd0ade7eba46c75d574...)` in any CloudWatch log stream.

I need to be able to monitor for this error. I spot checked it because I found it by chance since I was looking into the console. How can I monitor for this?

FYI, I use Data Dog too for log ingestion. Maybe that can help?

Comment: Which metric are you looking at in CloudWatch that indicates it ran without errors? As for the logs, I believe that error will show up in CloudTrail, not CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: Brief explanation: from ECS Cluster console, I go to Scheduled tasks. Then, when I click on any of my Scheduled tasks, a new windows shows up. This window shows info about the scheduled task. Among this info, there is a link that takes me to Cloud Watch and it only shows 2 metrics: TriggeredRules and Invocations. But in theory tehre are more, check this out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-monitoring.html. In particular I was wondering how can I check FailedInvocations.

Comment: Maybe "FailedInvocations" metric is not available when your tasks is the type of "Scheduled"?

Comment: FailedInvocations should be one of the metrics available in CloudWatch. Go into CloudWatch and look at all the metrics instead of looking at what the ECS console shows.

Comment: Not there https://pasteboard.co/nvaTIwuS0iTe.png